# Minus and not in gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I want to display the votes that are not completed and the currentuser is not involved in these votes.

I started by these criteria:

```
def displayAdherantByVote(){
            def adherant=springSecurityService.currentUser.username

             def elec=Election.withCriteria(){
              createAlias("adherant", "adherant")
                 createAlias("candidature", "candidature")

                       eq('adherant.firstName',adherant)

               projections{
                     property('candidature.vote')

               }
```

```
def newvote(){
        def votes= Vote.createCriteria()
        def results=votes.list{
         ge("enddateelection",new Date())

           le("startdateelection",new Date())
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, the code you posted is too incomplete. What do you mean by "the current user is not involved in these votes"? Please, describe more precisely that you want to do.

Comment: if the current user sees a vote and the vote is still open, it does not appear in this user
is ca I'm looking and I stuck in this share

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, you want to avoid displaying an Election where `candidature.firstname` is the same as the `username`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a negation `NOT` in Gorm you can use:

**ne** (check if 2 values are not equal)

**neProperty** (check if 2 properties are not equal)

So in your case I would check if the `currentUser` is not involved in a vote using a criteria:

```
neProperty("currentUser", "user")
```